# How to know when Amazon DynamoDB Completed BatchRequest?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've created tool that imports about 50-250 thousands rows to the database, the problem is that I don't know when it's been completed.

I'm using WriteRequestBatch from the PHP SDK:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-dynamodb.html#using-the-writerequestbatch

Is there any way to know when It's done?

Comment: If the code completes execution without error, then it's done. :-)

Comment: @JeremyLindblom Don't think that's true.  But, you can do a read with ConsistentRead true and it will wait until the previous write is complete.

Comment: When "it's done" writing and when the data has been fully replicated to every node are two different concerns, but yes, a ConsistentRead would definitely help with the latter.